# Почему через HTTPS сайт долго загружается?

Tags: apache, nginx, битрикс, centos, ssl

Недавно получили сертификат SSL для сайта организации. После установки и настройки сайт стал грузиться до 10-15 секунд. Сайт стоит на BitrixVM5.1 с CentOs. Настройка nginx и apache проводилась элементарная, включить ssl, указать путь до сертификата.
Wireshark при многократном тестировании показывает одну и ту же картину: ServerHello возвращается строго через 10 секунд.

[image: wireshark]

Как подробней узнать, куда деваются эти 10 секунд?

Comment: 1. сайт обслуживается сразу двумя серверами? или один из них выполняет функции proxy? тогда зачем настраивать ssl на втором из серверов, «внутреннем»? 2. код сайта «в курсе», что при отдаче «абсолютных» ссылок (вида `схема://адрес`) надо в качестве схемы подставлять https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в конфигурации nginx, а точнее в устаревшем наборе шифров.

## было

ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;

## стало

ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4";